# DataPager does not load new pages for ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, datapager

I have a DataPager control that I am using with my ListView and when the page loads the pager shows the first, next, last, preivous, and 10 pages but when I click any of the buttons or the hyperlinks for a page nothing happens, no matter how many times I click. I have heard that you have to do something in preredender but have not see any code on how this works. Can anyone tell me what code I am supposed to put in prerender (and how to call the prerender) if that is the solution and if it is not how to get my datapager working?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSearchResults" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMSG" CssClass="ErrorText" runat="server" />

        <asp:Panel ID="plSearchResults" runat="server">
            <table  style="width: 100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Literal ID="lblTitleRow" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Literal ID="lblDescriptionRow" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="TableSelectButton">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewItem" Text="Select" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <asp:ListView ID="lvSearchResults"  runat="server">

                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                    </LayoutTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%#Eval("Title")%>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%#Eval("Descript")%>
                            </td>
                            <td class="TableSelectButton">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnEditItem" Text="Select" PostBackUrl='<%#String.Format("{0}.aspx?ID={1}&SectionID={2}", Eval("PageName"), Eval("ID"), ddlMediaTitle.SelectedValue.ToString())%>' runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:ListView>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>

        <div class="Center">
            <asp:DataPager ID="dpSearchResults" PagedControlID="lvSearchResults" PageSize="10" runat="server"> 
                <Fields> 
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowNextPageButton="false" ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true" /> 
                    <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10" /> 
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowLastPageButton="true" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" /> 
                </Fields> 
            </asp:DataPager>
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>

    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where are you binding data on post back.. check on that. as i cant see the source code for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get your code sample to work by doing two things. First in the list view control I added the OnPagePropertiesChanged event and bound the data again.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvSearchResults"  runat="server" 
    OnPagePropertiesChanged="lvSearchResults_PagePropertiesChanged">
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void lvSearchResults_PagePropertiesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bind the lvSearchResults
}
```

In order to get the update panel to work I used this trigger instead:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lvSearchResults"
        EventName="PagePropertiesChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

One recommendation I have is to add update panels absolutely last after you have everything working. They seem to hide a lot of problems and make them more difficult to solve.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks when I get home from work I will test this solution and let you know how that works.

Comment: This has worked, I did not need to add the trigger, just the OnPageProperitedChanged with a rebind in the codebehind for that event. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that the list view control is one of the known controls that cannot be used within the update panel control. Test this by temporarily removing your update panel tags.

Comment: If that is the case then how would I dynamicly fill the listview based off selections of dropdowns?

Comment: Just allow the page to do a full post back.

Comment: I am now allowing a full post back and if I click a button the active page will change but the data in the list view does not.

Answer (score 0):

If the list view data is fiiled programatically with plSearchResults.DataSource = .???. , so it is called every postback in your page... Includin the async ones.

And the DataSource object must have the pager callback implemented.

So the solution for you. (if im assuming correctaly) is:
Add a  line in the code like this..

```
if(!isPostBack) //This line will assure tha the binding will be filled just once
    plSearchResults.DataSource = .???.
```

Then it will not rebind every postback...
AND be sure that the callbacks for paging are implemented on the DataSource Object

The Asp.NET data source objects like SQLDataSource, LinqDataSource, EntitiesDataSource... all them have the paging implemented. If you are creating one datasource programaricaly, you must implement the paging callbacks.

Comment: The DataSource and DataBind are already in a !isPostBack call. I am note sure have you mean by "If you are creating one datasource programaricaly, you must implement the paging callbacks."